# Camel Kafka Failed to update metadata

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-kafka

I am trying to push message to kafka using camel. I took camel sample code from camel git repo. I ran MessagePublisherClient.java and got below exception. I have configured my Kafka server name, port and topic details in property file.

Why I am getting this exception and how to fix this exception.

If I try with camel 2.14.1 version and code change as per 2.14.1. I am able to push message. But why latest version is getting error.

Camel Repo:
https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-kafka

Java 1.8
Camel : 2.21.0

Error:

```
Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[DirectToKafka     ] [DirectToKafka     ] [direct://kafkaStart                                                           ] [     60017]
[DirectToKafka     ] [to1               ] [kafka:{{producer.topic}}                                                      ] [     60013]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-host-1513537490104-0-1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1846)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ExchangeHelper.extractResultBody(ExchangeHelper.java:713)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:515)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:511)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeaders(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:259)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeaders(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:253)
    at org.apache.camel.example.kafka.MessagePublisherClient.main(MessagePublisherClient.java:91)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
```

Comment: Kafka timed out... Are you sure you configured correctly and it's running?

Comment: Kafka is up and running. I am able to connect with camel-kafka version:2.14.1. But I am getting error If I use latest version